# Photoshop loves to open my images at 0.132% scale. How can a user adjust the default open scale?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scale

I'd say 80% of the time, Photoshop opens my reasonably sized JPGs at 0.132%. I would love for them to appear at 100% or 75% or some normal size. So that I don't have to adjust it every time.

Notice a dot in the center of photoshop. That is the image at 0.132%.
[image: Speck Showing Default Photo Scale]

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "default zoom photoshop" shows that there is no way to set default zoom within photoshop, however, many users have experienced problems similar to yours.

A synopsis of the posts located here:
http://www.photoshopforums.com/photoshop-default-zoom-has-changed-vt21963.html

One can perform a workspace reset prior to beginning operations, clearing previous configurations.

> Their instructions are that while starting Photoshop, you immediately
>   hold down: ctrl+alt+shift (Windows) or Command+Option+Shift (Mac OS).

If you have custom workspace settings you would have to reset them.

The other option suggested in the above link is a bit more obscure:

> The problem occurs whenever the photoshop workspace (the grey empty
>   area behind documents) is smaller in area than the file you are
>   opening.

If these answers will not resolve your problem, consider a search using the above terms and select as many links as needed to find the winning answer.

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote your answer, but my OP was downvoted so I now only have 14 points and can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this (Maybe !)
Open your Photoshop CS6, Do not open using any image, Raw. Press Z, on the above panel, choose one of the options: Resize Windows to fit or Zoom All Windows(my prefer) or Scrubby Zoom or Actual Pixels or etc...

Then close the Photoshop CS6, Next time you run it it and open an image, it will show your image as the option you chose.